# Get the class for a generic collection without using an instance

Tags: java, reflection, parameterized

Iwould like to do something like the following:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        map.put("key1", new HashSet<String>());

        Set<String> theSet = getObjectAs(map, ***Set<String>.class***);
    }

    private static <T> T getObjectAs(Object object, Class<T> cls){
        return cls.cast(object);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, I can't get the class object out of that Set using .class (see in bold) because it is parameterized.

I want to make that method to return a Set who's type may vary (it won't always be a set of Strings) but which I know and I can give as a parameter.

Is there another way of doing something like this?

Comment: What is the use-case exactly?  You are creating the "map" already typed.  You don't even need the "getObjectAs" method.  All you need to do is: Set< String > theSet = map.get( "key1" );

Comment: Casting a map to a set will not work either - getObjectAs(map, Set<String>.class);

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can possibly do this is to accept that you need to do unsafe casts.  There is no such thing as `Set<String>.class`, because it would be exactly equal, in every respect, to `Set.class`.

The only other thing you might be able to do is use one of the "generic Class" types from a library somewhere, like [Guava's `TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html), but this wouldn't let you get around the need for unsafe casts -- it would only let you specify it with generics.  Guava's [`TypeToInstanceMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToInstanceMap.html) works similarly.